# Windows.Old keeps reappearing in each drive of the system even after delete and keeps increasing in size

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows.old

I have installed windows 10 creators update recently. I have been noticing a strange behavior in my system lately. A Windows.Old folder is created in each and every drive of my PC. Even if i delete it through Disk Cleaner. It keeps coming back and keeps growing in size. I know that after major update, Windows.Old folder is created in C Drive as a backup of previous windows files but in my case it is created in every drive. It is clogging up all the space in my hard disk. I have no idea weather it is a virus OR windows issue. I have scanned my system with Windows Defender and also doesn't seem to cure the issue, So any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

I am uploading Images of the problem. [C Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBdhw.jpg), [D Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovL2Z.png)

I have found that files named as "g3EE2.temp.exe" and "g93E2.temp.exe" are responsible for growing size of windows.old folder in every drive. Names of these files seemed very unusual so i ended these background processes through task manager. It seemed to stop the growing size of windows.old folder. but as soon as i rebooted the system. The problem came back. I scanned my system with avast. it doesn't appear to fix the problem

Comment: I'd run a quality offline antivirus/anti-malware scan, as Windows Defender isn't even close to being a quality antivirus (last independent testing I saw showed it in the 80% range, whereas a quality one would be in the 99-100% range).

One thing is certain: Windows isn't the cause of your issue. Windows creates the Windows.old folder when it performs a major update/upgrade. It's a one time process & nothing is added to it once the update/upgrade is finalized. It's also only created on the partition housing the %WinDir%, and nothing can autorun from Windows.old, as it's no longer mapped.

Comment: After looking at your screenshot of D, do you by chance have your program files or x86 folder mapped to the Softwares folders on D? I'd recommend downloading [QDir](http://www.softwareok.com/?Download=Q-Dir&goto=../Download/Q-Dir_Portable_x64.zip), extracting it to a directory, booting into WinRE (cmd prompt, execute notepad, navigate to QDir directory, then run it as admin (Extras -> System -> Show Hidden... ).  I'd delete every user's local temp folder, and every Windows.old folder.  Empty the recycle bin before exiting WinRE.  If the folder comes back, it's highly likely a virus or malware.

Comment: I have not mapped Program File x86 to any other folder. The folder name just happened to be Software. It is just a folder containing setups of Visual Studio, SQL server etc.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is not caused by Microsoft Windows, but by a piece of malware.

There are 2 options:

- do a full reinstall of Windows
- try to delete the malware using an antimalware/antivirus tool

The first option is better because it ensures all traces of the malware are removed. However, it requires more work to reinstall all the software you are using and reconfigure your settings. I would recommend the first option.

**Step 1**: ensure you have complete and usable backups.

**Step 2**: Check if you have a suspicious looking task in the Task Scheduler. For example a .DLL file that is being run from C:\ProgramData.

To open the Task Scheduler, press the Windows + R keys on your keyboard to open Run, and then type taskschd.msc in the Open field. Finally, click or tap on OK, or press Enter on your keyboard.

**Option 1**: Resetting Windows

- in the Start Menu, go to Settings (aka the Configuration screen)
- Click Update & Security
- Click Recovery
- Click the "Get started" button under "Reset this pc"

**Option 2**: MalwareBytes

- Dowload and install MalwareBytes from https://www.malwarebytes.com/ (it is free, no need to pay for it).
- Right-click the tray icon and check for updates
- Let MalwareBytes do a full scan of your computer
- Hope that it removed everything

For more information about this malware, you can read:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6m3d65/windowsold_folder_keeps_coming_back_and_creating/

Specifically the answers provided by user Bo98.

Answer (score -1):

I had a simular problem. I found that you must have the Windows 10 OS remove the folders. This a link for step-by-step instructions.

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-delete-windows-old-folder-in-windows-10/

Comment: You should provide detailed instructions, within the answer itself, simply linking to the instructions is not helpful to the community.  Be sure to provide all relevant information in the body of your answer, cite and quote your source, otherwise it's considered plagiarism.

Comment: Additionally, if you would read the question again, the author indicated they already tried the Disk Cleanup tool and claims it the folder keeps coming back.  There are also three different solutions, it's not clear, which approach you are actually suggesting will help the author.  I am not making this comment to be mean, I am making this comment, because link-only answers are not acceptable here at Superuser.

Comment: Actually i have tried all these three steps already. The folder keep reappearing back. Also. "THE FOLDER IS CREATED IN EACH DRIVE OF MY WINDOWS PC". I am a computer programmer. I know how windows.old works. But this is not usual behavior. "IT KEEPS INCREASING IN SIZE DAY BY DAY".